# Can I programmatically resume the Visual Studio Profiler launched with profiling paused?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, profiling, automated-tests

I have a simple case where I just want to delay the start of the profiling until a certain part of my automated test case. I want to avoid user interaction. I have been launching it from "Performance Explorer" in VS2013 Pro. I have the session run vstest.console.exe (without instrumentation) which in turn executes the tests in my Test.dll (with instrumentation). It works perfectly well when I start it without profiling paused. But trying to resume the profiler from Test.dll doesn't seem to work. I reference Microsoft.VisualStudio.Profiler in my Test.dll, then call:
`DataCollection.ResumeProfile(ProfileLevel.Global, DataCollection.CurrentId);`
At the point where I want to resume profiling. It doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?